# NGRX reducer not getting triggered

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am implementing NGRX in my Angular 10 application and seem to have a problem with calling the reducer. I have created a checkbox in the app component. I am trying to maintain it's toggle state. I have created an action and reducer. I am not sure why the reducer is not getting called. I have written a console.log in the reducer which doesn't seem to fire. I haven't used strong typing of Action names but have ensured the names match.

**app.module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(appReducer, {})
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkMe" (change)="checkChanged()" [checked]="displayCode" />
<label for="checkMe">Check Me</label>
```

**app.component**

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      title = 'Angular-NGRX-Practice';
      displayCode: boolean;
    
      constructor(private store: Store<any>) {
    
      }
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.select('app').subscribe(
      app => {
        if (app) {
          this.displayCode = app.showCheck;
        }
      });
  }
    
      checkChanged(): void {
        console.log('check changed fired!!!');
        this.store.dispatch(
          { type: '[App] Toggle Check box' }
        );
      }
    }
```

**app.reducer**

```
import { createAction, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';

export const appReducer = createReducer({ showCheck: true },
  on(createAction('[App] Toggle Check box'), state => {
    console.log('Original State: showCheck', JSON.stringify(state));
    return {
      ...state,
      showCheck: !state.showCheck
    };
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a slight change to `app.module.ts` when registering the reducer

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ app: appReducer })
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvt6q8)